# How to check which Lats and Longs I have crossed until now using my current location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location

I have a list of Latitude and Longitude stored in an Arraylist, together these lats and longs forms a Polyline. Now I want to check which Lats and latitude of the list that I have crossed until now. Is it possible to do that?

I am getting my current Lats and Longs through GPS.

I have gone through `isLocationonPath` method but it just returns true or false statement showing whether my location is on the list or not instead I want to check which lats and longs I have crossed until now from the list.

Comment: you mean you used `com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil`? and what exactly does `"I want to check which lats and longs I have crossed until now from the list."` mean?

Comment: @pskink Just assume that I have a list of Latitude and Longitude together which forms a polyline or route. Now I want to check which Latitude and Longitude from the list that I have crossed or I have traveled from it by comparing it with my current Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: so simply speaking you want to check if some location is inside that polyline?

Comment: @pskink Yeah I want to check whether my location is inside my polyline or not and I can do that using PolyUtil method but it just returns true or false instead I want to know which Latitude and Longitude from the list that I have crossed or I have traveled from it e.g. My list contains 4 rows each row contains a Latitude and Longitude now in a button click I want to know how much rows that I have covered until now. e.g. 2 rows covered, 3 rows covered.

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you really want

Comment: @pskink no problem its ok.

Comment: @pskink hey I have simplified my question please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016863/how-to-compare-locations